# Trying to program a piano staff/stave. Is this what it's supposed to look like?

Tags: piano

I'm currently writing a software application which creates notes on a staff, when a piano key is pressed. Unfortunately I have no background in music, and thus am finding it quite hard to get started.

Could someone kindly tell me if the following screenshot represents what it would look like on the staff (approximately) if someone presses all the white keys on a 25-key keyboard (15 white, 10 black) from left to right, and then from right to left?

Am I on the right track, or is this completely wrong? (The notes are just displayed as circles for now - im trying to get the positioning right).

Comment: You need [ledger lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledger_lines) for notes beyond the bounds of the staff

Comment: Also, watch out for wheel reinvention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scorewriters

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to get the 'positioning' right. As in, are the notes in the correct places or not, if they should start from somewhere else, etc.

Comment: It seems to me the lower notes are incorrectly aligned. E.g. the E note should be in the middle of the lowest line.

Comment: Honestly, No...The positioning does not look right.  I would do some research on how to read music.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... More of a music question... The question certainly has nothing to do with C# or .NET as it is tagged...

Comment: Your notes seem to drift apart from the lines in the lower area. The distance between notes should be half a line, so the notes are either in the middle between two lines, or the line goes through the center of the dot.

Comment: I would say the position is too loose. (1) You need lines to mark the low C and A (lowest and 3rd lowest notes) and one to mark the high B.

More critical is the G (second line) without the F and the A below and above it for context could be construed to be an F.

STRONGLY recommend you retain a musician to work with you because music, initially is simple, but has hundreds of years of nuance built in. OT, I strongly urge you to learn an instrument. You'll be a better (yes, I said "better") person for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.  You need a few extra things.  (NB. This is a simplified list just to get you going.  Music notation is a complex beast that can take years of study to master)

1. A [Clef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef).  Presumably in this instance you're looking for a treble clef.
2. You need to imagine that there are invisible lines ([ledger lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledger_lines)) above and below the 5 you can see.    In your example, the very first note played is immediately below the first of the invisible lines at the bottom, so you need to draw that as part of the note. (See the example on the wikipedia page I linked to.)
3. Obviously, note duration is required, but you mention you're already on that so I won't talk about it here.
4. A [Key signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature) to tell the player what key the music is in, and therefore what sharps and flats to expect

There's a lot more to drawing music on a stave than meets the eye, I'm afraid, but these should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at examples of sheet music. That may be helpful.

For instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_music

Answer (score 0):

I think so..

But what I'm missing at the most left side of the staff is the 'key'. This is pretty important.